# Error while installing symfit library in Python

Tags: python, pip, symfit

I get an error while installing symfit library.

I use pip3 in cmd to install the library.

here's the error in cmd:

```
Collecting symfit
  Using cached symfit-0.5.2.tar.gz (943 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12 in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from symfit) (1.18.1)
Collecting scipy<1.2,>=1.0
  Using cached scipy-1.1.0.tar.gz (15.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy>=1.2 in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from symfit) (1.5.1)
Collecting toposort
  Using cached toposort-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from symfit) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from sympy>=1.2->symfit) (1.1.0)
Installing collected packages: scipy, toposort, symfit
  Attempting uninstall: scipy
    Found existing installation: scipy 1.4.1
    Uninstalling scipy-1.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.4.1
    Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Amirhosein\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-92y759qu\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Amirhosein\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-92y759qu\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Amirhosein\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pr5dotd5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\scipy'
         cwd: C:\Users\Amirhosein\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-92y759qu\scipy\
    Complete output (147 lines):

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\amirhosein\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Amirhosein\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-92y759qu\scipy\setup.py", line 474, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\Amirhosein\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-92y759qu\scipy\setup.py", line 470, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\Amirhosein\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-92y759qu\scipy\setup.py", line 388, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1033, in add_subpackage
        config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
      File "c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 999, in get_subpackage
        config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
      File "c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 941, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1033, in add_subpackage
        config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
      File "c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 999, in get_subpackage
        config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
      File "c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 941, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 19, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of scipy
  Moving to c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy-1.4.1.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\Amirhosein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\~cipy-1.4.1.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\
   from C:\Users\Amirhosein\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\~cipy
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Amirhosein\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-92y759qu\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Amirhosein\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-92y759qu\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Amirhosein\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pr5dotd5\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\amirhosein\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\scipy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also installed the dependencies

sympy, numpy, scipy

Comment: It would help to know the OS you are working on.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have installed 32 bit python on purpose, otherwise install the 64 bit version instead

The error message is caused by the fact that `symfit` on pypi has requirement `scipy<1.2,>=1.0`:

> `Collecting scipy<1.2,>=1.0`

That is why your installation is uninstalling your scipy 1.4 and downloads version 1.1. Since it has no wheels for python 3.8 (too old) it downloads the source code and then fails because it cannot find a C compiler.

> `No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler'`

What you should do is install `symfit` from the github repository, as it has been updated since the last release to have requirements that are compatible with python 3.8:

```
 pip install git+https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit
```